# How to take backup by schema wise in SAP HANA

Tags: hana, database-backups

I am performing a backup in HANA using

```
hdbsql HDB=> BACKUP DATA USING FILE ('/backup/HDB/data/BACKUP_FULL_20170514/SAPHANA')
```

Instead of this I would like to have a backup by schema wise and make it as a cronjob. How to take backup by schema wise in SAP HANA?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, this is a common question, not just for HANA but for any DBMS with schema support.
The short answer is: it's not possible to backup/restore data based on schemas. A schema is a namespace in the database, while backup/restore are functions of the data persistence.

As transactions can span multiple schemas, restoring just a single schema might lead to inconsistencies, as transactions would only be partly recovered.

Having said all that, typically the actual requirement is not to backup/restore separate schemas, but to allow for the handling of multiple database tenants on a shared system.

SAP HANA supports this with Multi-Database-Containers. Each tenant gets its own set of database processes, memory, filesystems, etc. but the HANA software installation is shared.

That way it's easy to backup/recover a single tenant without affecting the other tenants. Another benefit with this approach is that the schema itself will have the same name in all tenant DBs, making maintenance easier.

Comment: Ok but when I use the above command it backups in what basis?Because it randomly creates 5 partition and I am sure those are not schemas.

Comment: HANA systems have several processes with independent storage files. For a consistent backup each process' persistency needs to be backed up - these are the different files you find.

Comment: I found that I can export a schema to save as a backup with `export <schema name>."*" AS BINARY INTO '<path>' with replace`. So will that be a solution to take backup schema wise and I will be able to identify which schema is in which file.

`

Answer (score 2):

You can export a schema with this SQL command:

```
EXPORT "MY_SCHEMA".* AS BINARY INTO '/tmp/my_schema' WITH REPLACE;
```

See [EXPORT documentation](https://help.sap.com/viewer/4fe29514fd584807ac9f2a04f6754767/2.0.01/en-US/20da0bec751910148e69c9668ea3ccb8.html) for more options.

Tipp: Do not export to a mounted Windows file system or NAS, because the export can contain case-dependent files with the same name but different casing. This would break on a Windows file system. -- Best is to directly compress it on the Linux system like so:

```
tar -czf my_schema.tgz /tmp/my_schema/
```

To import the schema backup, use this command:

```
IMPORT "MY_SCHEMA".* FROM '/tmp/my_schema' WITH REPLACE;
```

You can use `WITH RENAME "MY_SCHEMA" TO "MY_SCHEMA_COPY"` to restore it under a different name. See [IMPORT documentation](https://help.sap.com/viewer/4fe29514fd584807ac9f2a04f6754767/2.0.01/en-US/20f75ade751910148492a90e5e375b8f.html) for more options.

SAP note [2134959](http://service.sap.com/sap/support/notes/2134959) describes the process in more detail. Also, have a look at SAP note [2121486](http://service.sap.com/sap/support/notes/2121486), which lists the inconsistency risks of using `EXPORT` for backup, as mentioned by @Lars.

BTW, I am not sure why @Lars discourages this or even depicts it as "not possible". SAP itself recommends it and a lot of their tools rely on it, like SAP Cloud Control Center. It is a well-suited method for certain tasks, *on top* of a regular full backup.

Comment: There's nothing wrong with an export - it's just not a backup of the database. Users, roles, assigned privileges for example are not part of an export. Also you cannot recreate the database as it has been by using an export. Generally, using export requires dealing with many dependencies manually- that's why SAP provides tooling around that approach when we use it. The OP asked for a schema-backup which my answer addressed that.

Answer (score -1):

I use this simple commands:

In SHH go to your backup folder,
create your folder to contain the backup,
give that folder permissions to HANA Studio write in there:

```
cd /hana/bkps/
mkdir BACKUP_FLD_180101
chmod -R 777 BACKUP_FLD_180101/
```

Next go to HANA STUDIO make your backup with:

```
export "FLD_PRD"."*" AS BINARY INTO '/hana/bkps/BACKUP_FLD_180101' with replace threads 10
```

DONE!!